# How do I customize tooltips in ggplotly to reflect the x and y axis labels?

Tags: r, r-markdown, tooltip, histogram, ggplotly

Is it possible to customize the labels in `ggplotly()` tooltips to reflect the labels of your charts x and y axes, and if so, how is this done. For clarity, by tooltip labels, I mean the parts circled in red, and by x and y axes labels, I mean the parts circled in green in the image below.
[image: Example Plot]

I am making an interactive document using R Markdown, and have made a histogram where the user can select a variable to display from a number of variables in a data frame. Here is my code:

```
---
title: "Title"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

{r, echo = FALSE}

library(epiDisplay)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(plotly)

dataSet <- mtcars

selectInput(inputId = 'dataColumn',
            label = 'Please select a variable to examine',
            choices = names(dataSet))

sliderInput(inputId = 'bin',
            label = 'Please select the number of breaks',
            min = 5,
            max = 50,
            value = 30)

renderPlotly(ggplotly(ggplot(dataSet,
                  aes(dataSet[,input$dataColumn])) + 
             geom_histogram(bins = input$bin,
                            fill = "#3379b7",
                            color = "#3379b7",
                            alpha = 0.9) +
             xlab(paste(input$dataColumn)) +
             ylab("Frequency") +
             theme_ipsum()))
```

I have tried a couple of things, including adding a `text` argument to the `aes()` function - which does nothing - as well as including a `tooltip` argument in various places -  which either does nothing, or returns an 'unused argument' error.

**Edit**
After looking at the answer below, I think what I am trying to accomplish, is not to add custom toolip labels, but rather to edit the x and y tooltip labels to reflect the labels on the axes. So, I would like the labels to read:
Frequency: 5
mpg: 15.39655

Or more generally:
y axis label: y axis value
x axis label: x axis value

Comment: What do you want your custom labels to say?

Comment: Question has been edited to include this info

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide a reproducible example I'm unable to test it, but this should work for you:

Where you add an arg to the `aes` level in your `ggplot` object, and then specify that `tooltip = c("text")` for `ggplotly`:

```
renderPlotly(ggplotly(ggplot(dataSet,
                             aes(dataSet[,input$dataColumn],
                                 text = paste("MY CUSTOM TEXT", input$dataColumn))) + 
                        geom_histogram(bins = input$bin,
                                       fill = "#3379b7",
                                       color = "#3379b7",
                                       alpha = 0.9) +
                        xlab(paste(input$dataColumn)) +
                        ylab("Frequency") +
                        theme_ipsum() +
                        theme(axis.title.x = element_text(color = "#333333",
                                                          size = 12,
                                                          hjust = 0.5,
                                                          margin = margin(t = 20, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)), 
                              axis.title.y = element_text(color = "#333333",
                                                          size = 12,
                                                          hjust = 0.5,
                                                          margin = margin(t = 0, r = 20, b = 0, l = 0)),
                              panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#dcdcdc"),
                              panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour  = "#dcdcdc"))),
             tooltip = c("text"))
```

Here is a smaller example with `mtcars`:

```
ggplotly(mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mpg,
             text = paste("Custom Count: ", mpg))) +
  geom_histogram(), tooltip = c("text"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have edited my question so that the code should be reproducible now. This is very helpful, and has set me off in the right direction. I implemented the changes you suggested, and after seeing the results, I think what I am trying to accomplish to to edit the x and y tooltip labels, and not to add custom labels.